# Maven validate - Get child module pom directories

Tags: maven

A business team outside of the development team needs some information out of a source controlled repo that we house source in. We're using Maven to perform our builds, and using Git for source control. What I want to do is get the reactor build order, and feed that into a script to automate some searching in Git to provide the business team what they need, but I need to make sure I'm telling Git to search the appropriate directories (and not just the root directory of the entire repo).

So obviously I can do something like `mvn validate` to provide me:

```
foo> mvn validate
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] foo
[INFO] sub_foo_1
[INFO] sub_foo_2
...
```

Except I have no way to take that and hand that off to Git for additional information because I don't know what directories any of the child modules live in.

Is there any way I can find out the path to the individual pom files that are part of the reactor build order?

Comment: Can't you use some command like `find * -name "pom.xml"`?

Comment: No. Not all pom files under a folder are built as part of a reactor order. Just because a pom exists under a folder does not mean it will be used. I need to know only modules that are used in a specific reactor build order only. Also, there is no guarantee that a pom will exist as a child. I understand convention is to have any child modules under the parent on the file system, but there is no guarantee on this system to follow that convention.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer, but it wouldn't have been my first choice; hoping somebody else will have something better. I was really hoping there was a native Maven way to do [something like] this.

Basically, I created a small plugin to print out the information.

Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <groupId>foo.bar.baz.demo</groupId>
    <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>test_plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo;
import org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.plugins.annotations.Mojo;
import org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject;

@Mojo(name = "print_pom_dir")
public class TestMojo extends AbstractMojo {
    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {
        MavenProject object = (MavenProject) this.getPluginContext()
                .get("project");
        getLog().info(
                "Pom directory: " + object.getBasedir().getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

Where I can put a build execution in the parent such as:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>foo.bar.baz.demo</groupId>
            <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <artifactId>test_plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</plugins>
```

So all child modules inherit it.

Then all I have to do is run `mvn foo.bar.baz.demo:test_plugin:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT:print_pom_dir` from the root pom, and stdout gets my data for my to regexp out.

I wonder if putting it to a file or something in the target area might be cleaner, but I'm not too clear on best practices for Maven and whether or not changing the target directory for something not related to the build is standard, or how to get the root to know about the output from all child executions of the plugin for that matter.